# Console Application exits on finish (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

It's not about code, though. But my console applications written in VS will exit as soon as the application finish its job (no matter debugging or directly opening by double clicking *.exe). How can I prevent this cause I need to see the output.

Comment: breakpoints, hacks (`std::cin.get()`), secret programme arguments (`if("--pause" == std::string(args[1]) { std::cin.get(); }`), write to file (i.e. pipe output via debugger options), `OutputDebugString` to Output window, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is about code.  In your console application you have the main() function and because this is C++ it will end with a `return 0;` statement (or similar).  To make your app pause when it has finished all you need to do is alter that last line to something like `return fgetc(stdin);` and it will now wait until you press the enter key.

But to expand on what BeyelerStudios said you might want to go a bit further than that and make it a bit smarter. So:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  _tprintf(L"Press the Enter key to exit\n");
  return fgetc(stdin);
#else
  return 0;
#endif
```

The Visual Studio Output window will display any string passed to the function OutputDebugString in DEBUG configuration.  So if you just want a string you can look at, you can use that.

Passing arguments into you function is probably the best solution, you could still pause in release builds, but it is going to require the most work.

There is one final method.  Rather than hit F5 open a command prompt (WindowsKey+R and type CMD), cd to the write directory and run you exe from there, all output will remain in the window after the program exists.  But this won't help if you need the debugger.

Hope that helps.